# How to get the dataSource for Kendo toolbar items?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo toolbar where I have one button for export and on left side of the header I want to add text dynamically from the dataSource but I am not sure how to get data for kendo toolbar items,  For columns I know if we add template function that provides the data but for that partticular row. How can I get the data for toolbar so I can display the text that is part of dataSource ?

config.js

```
toolbar: [
    {
        template: '<button class="btn btn-default k-grid-excel btn-sm pull-right">Export to Excel</button>',
    },
    {
        template:function(dataBound) { 
            console.log("data",dataBound);
            return '<p class="pull-left"><strong>this.dataItem.epcfName</strong></p>'
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I would suggest different approach. Use toolbar Add method to add new dynamic items.

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Comment: Look at the Kendo UI Toolbar Demo http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/toolbar/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In toolbar component I execute a command like this in console:

```
$("#toolbar").data("kendoToolBar");
```

There is no datasource, but I think you will find items in:

```
$("#toolbar").data("kendoToolBar").options.items;
```

Comment: Thanks i got the idea.